# Use previous row result when current row is null

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has daily records of transactions and some rows are missing data which will make plotting a daily graph inconsistent.

[image: Before I run the query]

I want a query to use the last row result when the current one is null so that it can look something like this:
[image]

The structure of my table looks like this:
[image]

I have tried working on this query to select the previous row and update the current row if it is null but is not dynamic.

```
SELECT BALANCE
FROM tbl_batch_balances_null
WHERE id = 
(select min(id) 
from tbl_batch_balances_null where id < '2' and balance is not null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  alfie;

CREATE TABLE alfie
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 store CHAR(1) NULL,
 product INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO alfie VALUES
( 7,'a',3),
( 8,null,null),
( 9,null,null),
(10,null,null),
(11,'a',1),
(12,'a',1),
(13,'a',1),
(14,null,null),
(15,null,null),
(16,'b',2),
(17,null,null),
(18,null,null),
(19,null,null);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT a.id,
       COALESCE(a.store, c.store) store,
       COALESCE(a.product,c.product) product
  FROM alfie a
  LEFT 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.*,
              MAX(y.id) y_id
         FROM alfie x
         JOIN alfie y
           ON y.id < x.id
          AND y.store IS NOT NULL
         WHERE x.store IS NULL 
        GROUP
           BY x.id
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id
 LEFT
 JOIN alfie c
   ON c.id = b.y_id
ORDER
   BY id;
```

| id | store | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | a | 3 |
| 8 | a | 3 |
| 9 | a | 3 |
| 10 | a | 3 |
| 11 | a | 1 |
| 12 | a | 1 |
| 13 | a | 1 |
| 14 | a | 1 |
| 15 | a | 1 |
| 16 | b | 2 |
| 17 | b | 2 |
| 18 | b | 2 |
| 19 | b | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6wQxYZ5aR2KSW9gyTMEcrn/1)